# when we will use user control?

Tags: asp.net

when and where we will use user control ? actually i want to ask it's best practices.

i have read on msdn about user control there it was written .

At times, you might need functionality in a control that is not provided by the built-in ASP.NET Web server controls. In those cases, you can create your own controls. You have two options. You can create:
"User controls= User controls are containers into which you can put markup and Web server controls. You can then treat the user control as a unit and define properties and methods for it."

i confused from first statement ? what he want to say ?

Comment: Learn how to ask good questions - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Hey Nishant, all your questions are obvious exam questions. Why don't you do all of us a favor and just cough up the $10 for a TestKing example exam instead? http://stackoverflow.com/users/430803/nishant

Comment: when and where we will having good questions ?

Comment: @bzlm because it's a bad practice

Comment: Tomorrow we will use it.

Comment: @Oded I suspect English is not a native language, as the profile states the location to be somewhere where Oriya is the official language.

Comment: now i have edited that question plz see again

Comment: @Nishant: thanks for the expansion on your question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - The question as it was originally was a single line. Nothing to do with English, everything to do with asking a question.

Comment: @BoltClock: Just dont feel like UserControls today.

Comment: actually sir i am begineer hat's why we do mistake ,i promise one day i will become like you ,it's my belive by the way thanks for commenting on mistake ?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html I recommend reading this. Especially "Grovelling is not a substitute for doing your homework". We'd love to help you, but you need to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we want to **reuse** code.